# How to convert null to 0 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

When `pressureSeaLevelRate` returns null I need to set it to 0

```
_currentData['pressureRate'] = data['observation']['pressureSeaLevelRate'];
```

Comment: what other values do you have?

Comment: `_currentData.pressureRate = data?.observation?.pressureSeaLevelRate ?? 0`

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `if`? `if (... === null) { ... = 0 }`

Comment: @MichaelM. If any of the already available questions here on SO have the same problem/topic like this one then use one of those to close the question as duplicate of that other question so we don't create yet another copy of an already available information/answer,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the [`??` Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing). Here's an example

```js
const a = null;

const b = a ?? 0;
console.log(b)

const c = 1 + (a ?? 0);
console.log(c);
```

With your code, you can do this:

```
_currentData['pressureRate'] = data['observation']['pressureSeaLevelRate'] ?? 0;
```

or, as [Mulan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633183/mulan) pointed out in the comments, if `data` or `data.pressureSeaLevelRate` could also be `null`, use:

```
_currentData.pressureRate = data?.observation?.pressureSeaLevelRate ?? 0
```

Comment: Like the one in the dupe target?

Comment: ?? 0  worked!  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have only numbers and [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/null), you could convert `null` to a number with [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus#usage_with_non-numbers).

```js
let value = null;

value = +value;

console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
_currentData['pressureRate'] = Number(data['observation']['pressureSeaLevelRate']);
```